# Unhiding and unfiltering excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I am trying to create a macro in excel to unhide and unfilter rows and columns on two sheets in two separate workbooks.  It works on the first sheet but for some reason it doesn't work on the second.  I am really confused on why this is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Unfilter()
Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2.xlsm").Activate
Sheet3.Activate

'Unhide and Unfilter columns and rows on original sheet
With ActiveSheet
.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2 ESI.xlsm").Activate
Sheet3.Activate
'Unhide and Unfilter columns and rows on update sheet
With ActiveSheet
.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What error messages are you getting? Also, where exactly does the code fail?

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages. It just doesn't unfilter. I think its failing at the line `Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2 ESI.xlsm").Activate`

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code to see if everything behaves as you want?

Comment: Tell me the sheet names ? ..

Comment: They are both Sheet3 just in separate workbooks.

Comment: By Saying `Sheet3.Activate` you're referring to the code name for a worksheet in your current workbook... Just change it to `Sheets("Sheet3").Activate`

Answer (score 0):

To un-filter data use (for example sheet 1):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
```

---

If data isn't already filtered you'll want to either test for it or just resume on error like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
```

---

Full Code

```
Sub Unfilter()
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook
    Set wbk1 = Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2.xlsm")

    On Error Resume Next
    wbk1.Worksheets("Sheet3").ShowAllData


    Dim wbk2 As Workbook
    Set wbk2 = Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2 ESI.xlsm")

    On Error Resume Next
    wbk2.Worksheets("Sheet3").ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This .. If the sheet name is **sheet3** then you should use `SHeets("Sheet3").activate`

```
Sub Unfilter()
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2.xlsm")

With wb1.Sheets("Sheet3")
.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Set wb2 = Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2 ESI.xlsm")

With wb2.Sheets("Sheet3")
.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
.AutoFilterMode = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like it would fix it but for some reason it gives me a subscript out of range error.

Comment: It happens in the first `With` block.

Comment: i'm sure ..it will work if the sheet name and workbook name is correct

Comment: I typed in the sheet name wrong, whoops. It doesn't give me the subscript error anymore but it gives me an object defined error now...

Comment: Where .. in which line ?

Comment: In the first `With` Block.

Comment: I tested above code in my system.. and its working fine.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the problem. Do both workbooks have to be open?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62117/discussion-between-willis-zawisa-and-sathish-k).